# include works only when file is in same directory

Tags: php, include

I have this site I'm making. When I include a php file from the same folder it works but when I do

```
<?php include('/ioanblog/appstore/header.php');?>
```

it doesn't work or

```
<?php include('http://www.domain.co.uk/appstore/header.php');?>
```

that isn't working either.

All the header is holding is a style sheet and Piwik code, it will also hold navigation.

[image]

Comment: you can not directly include file via `http://..`

Comment: but i dont want to use http to get the file

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @SumitBijvani since when?

Comment: the page is loading but no style has been added

Comment: Why are you including via php? Why not use a global stylesheet?

Comment: i also have js that has the be in the page html and i may need it for future use

Comment: Which directory are you trying to include it *from*?

Comment: libreoffice directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) on relative paths.

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

You are using `/ioanblog/…` which is an **absolute** path. I suspect your site is in `/var/www/public_html/ioanblog/…` or `/home/user/ioanblog/…` or something similar, **not** in `/ioanblog/…`. You should remove the first `/` making it a *relative* instead of an absolute path. You might have to go "up" to parent directories like `../contents/header.php` or `../../contents/header.php` for the actual file.

As [pointed out by brbcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646049/include-works-only-when-file-is-in-same-directory/15646106?noredirect=1#comment22201560_15646106) it should probably be `../../header.php`. But first make sure you understand absolute/relative paths!

You might also want to read up on [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to 'convert' relative paths to absolute paths.

Comment: Read it, OK. But *understood* it too?

Comment: kind of. oh and my hosting is shared hosting

Comment: Sorry if I sound harsh, I don't intend to, but what use is it to say "I've already read that" when you don't understand (most/some of) what it's saying? Why don't you then just say or point out what exactly you don't understand? Your entire problem seems to stem from the fact that you don't understand the difference between relative and absolute paths. So the first thing you'll need to do is figure out which is what and when to use which. Randomly trying paths until it works (maybe seemingly) will get you a quick fix this time until next time you run into the same problem. Then what do you do?

Comment: yeah ok. what about the vps hosting

Comment: It's not in the `./contents` directory... I mis-read that too. It's simply two directories up. `../../`.

Comment: "*what about the vps hosting*" What about it? There are millions of websites hosted on VPS; why would that matter for your problem at hand? I don't see the relation to be honest.
@brbcoding: Doesn't matter; it's the *concept* IoanLoosley doesn't get which is far more important than the actual solution IMHO.

Comment: We are saying: Forget about your problem for 2 seconds, read up on what absolute/relative paths are and **then**, when you know your basics, go back to your problem and try to solve it. You can't solve this by randomly changing paths like a bull in a chinashop; you need to know what you're doing. So you need a grasp of the basic concept of absolute/relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say why the include won't work without knowing the folder structure.
But you can try it with the absolute path: /home/user/domain/public_html/etc...

Comment: because im on hosting that has very limited file access

Answer (score 1):

try removing the first slash so `include('ioanblog/appstore/header.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php include('../../header.php');?>`

That's my guess... You don't have an `appstore` directory anywhere as far as I can tell.

EDIT: Updated with the correct path... Coming from the `libreoffice` directory.